# Importing Existing Rails Application to RubyMine Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I am currently having unnecessary trouble trying to test out RubyMine. My biggest problem is that I cannot find a way to take a existing rails application on my system and convert it to an official RubyMine application, so that I can experience all of the features of RubyMine.

The only options that are available to me are to either create a new RubyMine rails project, to pull a rails project from a git remote (doesn't work), or to open a previous rails directory (which allows you to edit rails code, but it doesn't recognize this directory as a RubyMine project, so I cannot heap all of the benefits that RubyMine has for rails).

Please help me out, RubyMine seems promising

This is RubyMine 4 btw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`File` | `Open Directory` should create a new RubyMine project from the existing sources. I've just tried with a new Rails app and it recognized it as a Rails project and all the features work just like for the new project created from RubyMine.

Comment: Huh, so I tried this with a different rails application I had and it ended up working; however, it still does not work with this other rails application. Do you any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Deleting .idea dir and reopening helped me.

Comment: @gotqn, don't forget to add .idea directory to gitignore and better to a global one.